# O Python NLTK não classifica corretamente meu texto mesmo que no show_most_informative_features pareça tudo bem

Tags: python, nltk

Fala galera, estou aprendendo a mexer com NLTK do Python por um curso, utilizando a base exemplo do professor, tudo funcionar fino, mas ao utilizar uma base própria, algo estranho está acontecendo e como eu não manjo disso n consigo desempacar.

Estou tentando analisar um pequeno dataset (1000 linhas) de dados de um sistema interno aqui. O resultado do **"show_most_informative_features"**  é o esperado. Olhem:

```
              execut = True             1114 : 1790   =     91.2 : 1.0
                  r$ = True             1114 : 1790   =     56.2 : 1.0
                pens = True             1114 : 1790   =     40.1 : 1.0
                 val = True             1114 : 1790   =     39.8 : 1.0
                 pag = True             1114 : 1790   =     28.5 : 1.0
              parcel = True             1114 : 1790   =     24.1 : 1.0
                real = True             1114 : 1790   =     24.1 : 1.0
            municípi = True             2049 : 1790   =     23.6 : 1.0
             aliment = True             1114 : 203    =     22.2 : 1.0
              veícul = True             2049 : 1790   =     22.1 : 1.0
                   é = True             1114 : 1790   =     21.5 : 1.0
               efetu = True             1114 : 1790   =     21.2 : 1.0
          palmas/to, = True             1114 : 1790   =     21.2 : 1.0
                rend = True             2049 : 1790   =     20.5 : 1.0
                cont = True              178 : 1790   =     19.9 : 1.0
```

Essa é a cadeia de string que uso para testar o algorítimo:

```
['execut', 'r$', 'pen', 'val', 'pag']
```

Me baseando nessa tabela de features, eu estava esperando que o NLTK classificasse ela como **1114** (usei os top 5 radicais que mais tem chance de classificar assim), mas meu código insiste em classificar em "**1790"**

Olhando a problabilidade de classificação ( `print prob_classify()`), fica ainda mais estranho, pra mim:

CODE:

```
def show_distribuicao():
  distribuicao = classificador.prob_classify(linha_teste_frase)

  for classe in distribuicao.samples():
      print("%s: %f" % (classe, distribuicao.prob(classe)))
```

RESULT:

```
178: 0.000000
1790: 1.000000
203: 0.000000
1114: 0.000000
2049: 0.000000
```

Tem 100% de chance de classificar como  1790?? Como assim? E nem é pq tenho uma dissiparidade muito grande entre os tipos de dados, olha como está a contagem de valores (`qualificacao_id.value_counts()`):

```
1790    323
203     237
178     152
1114    147
2049    141
```

Aqui uma prévia (`head(10)`) do dataset que estou tratando:

```
Unnamed: 0                                          historico qualificacao_id
0         648   A assistida chegou de Portugal para a audiênc...             178
1         889   AP 0025466-03.2018.827.2729   Não tem condena...            1790
2        4315   o assisitido retornou dizendo que sua colação...             203
3        4512   Atendida: Lucélia Santos de Sousa (9255-0805)...            1790
4        7287   PEDI TESTEMUNHAS PARA RESPOSTA. ACUSADO DE RO...            1790
5        7422   O &nbsp;seu advogado &nbsp;particular renunci...             203
6        7526   (Juliana Dias)&nbsp;     A assistida comparec...            1114
7        8272     Tel (63) 9213-2485 Ranilson Martins da Silv...            1790
8        8576                                       Orientação.             2049
9        9438   Compareceu a Assistida para apresentar recibo...             178
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que está acontecendo?
PS: desculpem pelas noobisses nas teminologias, é que sou noob mesmo :P

Comment: Pelo o que você apresentou, a base parece estar **muito** desbalanceada. Muitos itens 1790 na lista. Tente balancear a base de treino.

Comment: Obrigado Paulo. Vou tentar fazer isso.